# Há uma diferença entre "curtir" e "gostar"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

Recentemente, eu mudei meu Facebook em português e eu vi que o Facebook não usa "gostar" quando você "like" mas "curtir".

Foi a primeira vez que eu vi essa palavra e me perguntei se ambos são sinônimos ou têm usos diferentes.

Desculpe pelos erros.

Comment: As duas palavras podem ser empregadas em frases e não mudar em nada o significado, então pode-se dizer que não há diferença entre `Curtir` e `Gostar`

Comment: Cuidado só com curtir, em Portugal pode ser usado como o "ficar" ai do Brasil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Brazilian Porguese, "curtir", meaning "like" or "enjoy" is a slang-word that has been around since the last decade of the twentieth century. It's used  informally and essentially among teen agers and younger adults. Examples:

- "curto muito esse tipo de coisa."
- "eu curto muito você" ("enjoy being with you, suggests some intimacy")
- "obrigado, mas não curto drogas"

In addition to being a slang word, "curtir" is informal, may suggest intimacy,  but you would be safe using it when you are among your peers.

The older and rarer usages can be found [here](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/curtir%20_938030.html)

Comment: Obrigado! Although all answers have been very helpful, yours was the most helpful with the explanation of its origin in Brazil and informal part.

Answer (score 8):

As duas palavras têm significados parecidos e pelo que pesquisei aparecem como sinónimos. Se puseres o Facebook em português de Portugal vai-te aparecer "gosto" e não "curtir" como se pode ver na imagem.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Em Portugal usamos mais "gostar" como ***like***.

> ### gos·tar
>
> (latim gusto, -are, provar) verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Achar bom gosto a (ex.: não gosto de cerveja). = APRECIAR
> 2. Ter prazer em ver ou em sentir (ex.: gostou do filme?).
> 3. Achar-se ou dar-se bem.
> 4. Ter inclinação.
> 5. Ter por hábito. = USAR
> 6. Simpatizar.
> 7. Provar.
> 8. Ter satisfação em. verbo transitivo e pronominal
> 9. Ter afeição. = ESTIMAR
>
> Antónimo Geral: DETESTAR, EXECRAR, ODIAR
>
> "gostar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/gostar [consultado em
>   15-09-2015].

---

Em Portugal curtir pode ter vários significados e é mais usado como calão ou como o "ficar" do Brasil

> Curti bue aquele filme que vimos ontem.
>
> Curti ontem com uma menina muito linda.

No dicionário da priberam:

> ### cur·tir
>
> (origem controversa) verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Preparar peles, couros para os tornar imputrescíveis.
> 2. Remolhar matérias têxteis para as abrandar e lhes poder separar as fibras.
> 3. Conservar alimentos em líquido adequado. = CURAR
> 4. Queimar a pele por exposição ao sol ou ao vento.
> 5. [Figurado]  Suportar sofrimento ou situação penosa. = AGUENTAR, PADECER, SOFRER
> 6. [Figurado]  Tornar mais forte, mais resistente. = CALEJAR, ENDURECER
> 7. [Informal]  Ressacar. verbo transitivo e intransitivo
> 8. **[Informal]  Sentir prazer ou satisfação; gostar muito de (ex.: ele** 
>      **curte ouvir música clássica). = APRECIAR, DELEITAR-SE, DESFRUTAR**
> 9. [Informal]  Trocar carícias sexuais.
>
> "curtir", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/curtir [consultado em
>   15-09-2015].

---

Comment: Curtir com a cara, por exemplo, tem significado oposto ao de gostar, Significar tirar sarro, fazer brincadeira de mal gosto com alguém.

Answer (score 5):

As únicas diferenças são que "curtir" é bem informal e também a regência dos verbos. "Gostar" é transitivo indireto (Ela gosta *de* goiaba) e "curtir" é direto (Ele curte tocar bateria).

Além disso, "curtir" também pode significar algo parecido com "enjoy":

> Luciana Gimenez aproveita férias para curtir os filhos.
>
> Nesse frio nada melhor do que ficar em casa e curtir um bom filme.

Curiosidade: o filme Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1986) é conhecido no Brasil como "Curtindo a vida adoidado".

Comment: A diferença nos exemplos é intencional? Isto é, _curtir_ usa-se mais para atividades, _curtir correr/jogar futebol/dançar_ do que para coisas? Posso dizer _eu curto goiabada?_

Comment: Que péssima nome deram ao filme...

Comment: Não foi intencional, mas agora que você mencionou, soaria meio estranho usar curtir em alguns casos, como comida (pelo menos para mim). Mas é comum ouvir alguém dizer que curte os filmes do Kubrick ou que (não) curte Fulano (no sentido de (não) achar Fulano uma pessoa agradável).

Comment: Ah @Jacinto, também atualizei a resposta com outro sentido do verbo curtir

Comment: @Jacinto "Eu curto goiabada" soa estranho.  Principalmente porque jovens não costumam elogiar goiabada.  Mas já ouvi dizer "nesse friozinho eu curto um bom vinho".  O exemplo acima também poderia ser dito "Nesse frio eu curto ficar em casa assistindo a um bom filme.

Comment: Acho que estou apanhando o espírito da palavra. No fundo _curtir_ é mais forte que _gostar_.

Comment: Curtir dá a ideia de se divertir. Este é um ponto que torna as curtidas em ptBR bizarras quando algo ruim ou trágico é curtido. Se fosse um "gosto" como em ptPT pareceria mais com um "concordo".

Answer (score 2):

As duas palavras podem ser empregadas em frases e não mudar em nada o significado, então pode-se dizer que não há diferença entre `Curtir` e `Gostar` sendo assim, as duas palavras passam a ser sinônimas(palavras diferentes que possuem o mesmo significado)